# Is this an appropriate way to rollback deletes in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, microservices

I have a microservice architecture where a `create` event in one microservice triggers a `create` in another using a messaging queue. However, I'm trying to implement some sort of rollback functionality in the scenario where the second service fails somehow.

I'm using mongoDB and to deal with failed writes, I figured I can just delete any previously created objects in the first service. My first thought was to use the oplog: I could send a timestamps to the second service and if something goes wrong, rollback to the upto the operation before the timestamp

How are deletes generally rolled back in these scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

If they work like:

- Service 1 Create A
- Service 1 Send Message A
- Service 2 Receive Message A
- Service 2 Create A

---

- Service 1 Create B
- Service 1 Send Message B
- Service 2 Receive Message B
- Service 2 Create B

---

- Service 1 Create C
- Service 1 Send Message C
- Service 2 Receive Message C
- Service 2 Create C

Then you can probably make do with a timestamp.

If it can go like:

- Service 1 Create A
- Service 1 Send Message A
- Service 1 Create B
- Service 1 Send Message B
- Service 2 Receive Message B
- Service 2 Receive Message A
- Service 2 Create B
- Service 2 Create A

Then no, because if A fails and B doesn't you delete B too.

You could start a transaction when creating on service 1 then send a message to  service 2 and get a message from service 2 that says if service 2 failed or not, if it failed you rollback from service 1 if it did not fail you commit.

Otherwise you could send an ID instead of timestamp then delete based on ID not timestamp.

Comment: Thanks I'll try out a couple of these, I think the timestamp or transaction methods should work. However I'm concerned about the transaction method since it sort of creates coupling between the services.